# In SQL Server 2000, is there a sysobjects query that will retrieve user views and not system views?

Tags: sql-server-2000, sysobjects

Assuming such a query exists, I would greatly appreciate the help.

I'm trying to develop a permissions script that will grant "select" and "references" permissions on the user tables and views in a database.  My hope is that executing the "grant" commands on each element in such a set will make it easier to keep permissions current when new tables and views are added to the database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select * from information_schema.tables
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(table_name),'IsMSShipped') =0
```

Will exclude dt_properties and system tables

add

```
where table_type = 'view'
```

if you just want the view

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    sysobjects
WHERE
    xtype = 'V' AND
    type = 'V' AND
    category = 0
```

Here is a list of the possible values for **xtype**:

- C = CHECK constraint
- D = Default or DEFAULT constraint
- F = FOREIGN KEY constraint
- L = Log
- P = Stored procedure
- PK = PRIMARY KEY constraint (type is K)
- RF = Replication filter stored procedure
- S = System table
- TR = Trigger
- U = User table
- UQ = UNIQUE constraint (type is K)
- V = View
- X = Extended stored procedure

Here are the possible values for **type**:

- C = CHECK constraint
- D = Default or DEFAULT constraint
- F = FOREIGN KEY constraint
- FN = Scalar function
- IF = Inlined table-function
- K = PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint
- L = Log
- P = Stored procedure
- R = Rule
- RF = Replication filter stored procedure
- S = System table
- TF = Table function
- TR = Trigger
- U = User table
- V = View
- X = Extended stored procedure

Finally, the **category** field looks like it groups based on different types of objects. After analyzing the return resultset, the system views look to have a **category** = 2, whereas all of the user views have a **category** = 0. Hope this helps.

For more information, visit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260447(SQL.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from information_schema.tables
where table_type = 'view'
```

Comment: Returns sysconstraints and syssegments that are not user views.